# How to make a sublist fill a fluid width <li> tag? (For navigation)

Tags: html, css, menu

The initial issue of menu hovering was solved down below, however I am looking at ways to make a droplist fill the width of a `<li>` tag even if the `<li>` tag is fluid width;

e.g `<li><a style="padding: 0 20px;>Test</a></li>`

I've created a basic design for what i want my menu system to be for my site however after re-drafting i've decided to create fluid width links and droplists rather than forced width. The issue is, on hovering on the link to reveal the droplist, the sublinks line up side-by-side rather than top-to-bottom and also it throws the next link out of the navigation system. If anybody could point me as to where my code is wrong I would be very greatful!

http://jsfiddle.net/vGSgJ/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navStore">
    <ul id="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    color: RGB(0, 0, 0);
    font: 14px Arial;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#navStore {
    background: RGB(100, 100, 100);
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav li:hover > a {
    background: RGB(255, 255, 255);
    color: RGB(100, 100, 100);
}

#nav li a {
    background: RGB(100, 100, 100);
    color: RGB(255, 255, 255);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

#nav li ul {
    border: 1px solid RGB(0, 0, 0);
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

#nav li ul li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li ul li a {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover {
    background: blue;
}

#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Add the following to your CSS:

### CSS

```
#nav li ul{
    position:absolute;
}

#nav li ul li{
    /*This part is already there*/
    float: left;
    /*New content*/
    clear:both;
}
```

[**JSFiddle** (edit)](http://jsfiddle.net/vGSgJ/2/)

---

## Explanation

The sub lists are still taking their place, (`display:block`, `position:relative`).
You can fix this issue setting their position `absolute` to their parent's position.

`clear:both` makes it so that there's only one element per block (horizontally)

---

## Javascript

[**Pure vs jQuery specific performance test case**](http://jsperf.com/purejs-vs-jquery-ul-li-ul-li-width-from-parent-a)

### The pure way

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
var parentWidth = Array();
for(var child in nav.childNodes)
{
    /*If the childNode is an Element Node */
   if(nav.childNodes[child].nodeType ==1)
   {
       var baseWidth = nav.childNodes[child].offsetWidth;
       var ul = nav.childNodes[child].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];

       ul.style.width = baseWidth;
       /* We want to get the children li elements */
       var ulChildren = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
       for(var li in ulChildren)
       {
           if(ulChildren[li].nodeType == 1)
           {

               ulChildren[li].style.width = (baseWidth) +"px";
           }
       }  
   }
}
```

### The jQuery way

```
$.each($('#nav li ul li'),function(){
    var desiredWidth = $(this).parent().siblings('a')[0].offsetWidth;
    $(this).width(desiredWidth);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However can I just ask, how do i go about lining up the `<li>` tags inside the sub lists? I want it fluid width so `width: 100%` wouldn't be effective as it doesn't have a set width to fill.

Comment: cheers :) i'll mark your answer as correct once it allows me too.

Comment: Cheers! I changed my mind on the fluid sub menus.. it doesn't look right :/ Only issue i got is because my `#nav li` is fluid because it takes it's width from the `<a>` tag nested inside, i can't make the sublist's width 100%, do you know any ways round this by any chance?

Comment: no worries man! You've done plenty to help as it is so it's much appreciated.

Comment: @LeeB So, you want the *sublist* to take the width of the parent a?

Comment: Basically yeah, as that is the element which sets the li width :)

Comment: Cheers! Just a quick Q, is it only possible to do something like this with jQuery? Was hoping (for now) for just a CSS solution but i suppose this adds to experience rather than making it the entire solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31595/discussion-between-ghillied-and-leeb)